# Can you propose to me two programs to make as project for my evolutionary computing class?

Tags: genetic-algorithm, evolutionary-algorithm, genetic-programming

My teacher wants us to make two projects, but we haven´t seen many topics and I don´t have very clear what evolutionary computing is used for. Can you give me some ideas, please?

Comment: There you go: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolved_antenna

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start is to identify something that can be improved with successive alterations. A great example is the design of a simple windmill propeller or turbine. Start of with a random design and arrangement of the blands. Input this geometry into the genetic algorithm and define the fitness as how fast the propeller spins based on a fixed air flow (a fan for example). Even if you do not build the fan, this is an interesting one to write about and should get you some marks!

Answer (score 0):

Some great problems for Evolutionary programming are the [Traveling Salesman Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) and [Knapsack Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem).

You may also want to consider another NP Complete problem like [Sudoku](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics_of_Sudoku). Sudoku is a good example of a problem that is possible to solve with stochastic optimization, but more efficient techniques exist. There are a number of [Sudoku Solutions Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics_of_Sudoku).

You could compare the difficulty of using evolutionary programming with the Sudoku problem to either the Traveling Salesman or the Knapsack problem and explain why the algorithm works well for the first 2 problems but not the Sudoku.